# Fatal Error :3:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. When trying to run web app

Tags: mysql, tomcat, netbeans, web

First time i've got this error. I have no idea what happened but it seems to say something about my context.xml file.

Here is the error from tomcat

```
[Fatal Error] :3:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
C:\Users\Nyco.tony-PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Apo\nbproject\build-impl.xml:724: 
Deployment error:
Tomcat configuration file C:\Users\Nyco.tony-PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Apo\web\META-    INF\context.xml seems to be broken. Please make sure it is parseable and valid.
See the server log for details.
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:232)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Caused by: org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.common.api.ConfigurationException: Tomcat configuration file C:\Users\Nyco.tony-PC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Apo\web\META-INF\context.xml seems to be broken. Please make sure it is parseable and valid.
at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.config.TomcatModuleConfiguration.getContext(TomcatModuleConfiguration.java:176)
at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.config.TomcatModuleConfiguration.getDatasources(TomcatModuleConfiguration.java:201)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.config.ConfigSupportImpl.getDatasources(ConfigSupportImpl.java:398)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.DeploymentHelper.deployJdbcDrivers(DeploymentHelper.java:87)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:180)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: DOM graph creation failed: org.netbeans.modules.schema2beans.Schema2BeansRuntimeException: Failed to create the XML-DOM Document.  Check your XML to make sure it is correct.
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.config.gen.Context.createGraph(Context.java:3178)
at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.config.gen.Context.createGraph(Context.java:3162)
at org.netbeans.modules.tomcat5.config.TomcatModuleConfiguration.getContext(TomcatModuleConfiguration.java:169)
... 20 more
```

and to think that I only have 3 lines on my context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Apo"/>
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/apo" password="user" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apo" username="myUser"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `Resource` tag inside the `Context` tag, e.g.:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Apo">
    <Resource auth="Container" .../>
</Context>
```

Comment: sadly, yes. just rechecked.

Comment: And there is no extra "/" at the end of your opening `Context` tag? It needs to end with ">", not with "/>".